Why is a python-polars dataset much larger after .unpivot?
I have a symmetric matrix of about 150k rows and columns in a polars dataframe. This takes some 100GB RAM, which is fine. When I try to .unpivot() the dataset (the polars unpivot, of course), however, my RAM shows that it uses about 600GB to unpivot, and after the unpivot, the dataset is about 400GB, much larger than before. Could someone explain to me why that is, and what I can do against it? It's not so bad that it uses so much RAM in the process, but I would really like the dataset to be the same size as when it started. Any pointers are appreciated!
Sample data: 
df = {
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [2, 1, 2],
    "C": [3, 2, 1], 
    "names": ["A", "B", "C"]
}
df = pl.DataFrame(df)
#this df is 100GB

df = df.unpivot(index = "names", variable_name = "names_2", value_name = "distance")

#output: 
df

shape: (9, 3)
┌───────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ names ┆ names_2 ┆ distance │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ str   ┆ str     ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ A     ┆ A       ┆ 1        │
│ B     ┆ A       ┆ 2        │
│ C     ┆ A       ┆ 3        │
│ A     ┆ B       ┆ 2        │
│ B     ┆ B       ┆ 1        │
│ C     ┆ B       ┆ 2        │
│ A     ┆ C       ┆ 3        │
│ B     ┆ C       ┆ 2        │
│ C     ┆ C       ┆ 1        │
└───────┴─────────┴──────────┘

#this df is >400GB large


Could you give an example sample data of a few rows and colums of the kind of data that you are trying to process and the expected result after melt for that example? It would help in understanding the problem.

Just thinking out loud, when you melt datafeame it has to conform all the columns into column of most common type which might take more space.

Apologies, I added sample data and code. I have numeric values in the matrix (I think) plus one column of strings, and column names. Afterwards I should have two columns of strings and one numeric (later transformed to categorical). I don't understand why this should be 4x the size , it doesn't really need to transform data types if I understand correctly?

Just look at your example: the input frame is 3x4, the output is 9x3

There is a feature request to melt into Categoricals directly to save on memory: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11876

@jqurious is there a way to do the melt directly into Categoricals 'by hand' and save on memory?

@NilsR I'm not aware of any way.

This might just be an issue where the OS doesn't see the memory being released.
For example if I do...
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [2, 1, 2],
    "C": [3, 2, 1], 
    "names": ["A", "B", "C"]
})

df.write_ipc('blah.ipc')
raw_size = Path('blah.ipc').stat().st_size


(
    df
    .unpivot(index = "names", variable_name = "names_2", value_name = "distance")
    .write_ipc("blah_unpivot.ipc")
)

unpivot_size= Path('blah_unpivot.ipc').stat().st_size

then unpivot_size is smaller than raw_size. Columns have a little bit of overhead so with very small frames, fewer columns will save memory.
If we make the initial df bigger then that is no longer the case as the number of values grows. For example, make the df initialize as 12x the length then unpivot_size will be bigger.
In that case you can do better by casting names_2 to an Enum like this...
enum =  enum=pl.Enum([x for x in df.columns if x!='names'])
(
    df
    .unpivot(index = "names", variable_name = "names_2", value_name = "distance")
    .with_columns(pl.col('names_2').cast(enum))
    .write_ipc("blah_unpivot_casted.ipc")
)

The amount of memory you can save with Enums will be relative to the length of your strings. For instance, if your Strings are only one character (as in this example) then you might only get a 20% savings by using Enums but if you have Strings that are 99 character it could be over 80%.
